# Process Builder activation error

Tags: process-builder, invocable-method, public, invocablevariable

I have a process builder that invokes a method from a class where it passes one of the three parameters. In the class the InvocableVariable is a List of Custom object Call__c but from process builder I am able to pass only one Call__c record.

After successfully saving the process builder, I am getting below error.

**Error:**

```
 Your changes are saved, but you can't activate this process until you resolve the following errors.
    The input parameter "callList" can accept multiple values, so the assigned value must be a flow variable with the isCollection property set to true.
```

Comment: is Call__c the same object that the Process Builder operates (starts) on? or a related via parent or child object?

Comment: Same object where process builder starts

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but you will get an error like this if you try to set an `@InvocableVariable` that is typed as a `list` from process builder:

```
global class InputTesting {
      @InvocableVariable(required=true)
      global String[] tst; 
}
```